# Who wins? I’ve got two pairs

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

Since the best five cards win, for example I have a J & 3, opponent with his J & 5.

The table has A, J, A, 3, 10.

So I should win the hands since I got two pairs originally? But with the best five cards I would have lost because they are a pair of aces on the table?

Need someone help to explain, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a split pot. You both have the same hand: two pairs (Aces and Jacks) with the fifth card being the Ten on the board.

Your other hole cards (your 3 and your opponent's 5) are irrelevant. Your "pair of 3's" counts for nothing because you already have a better two pair with Aces and Jacks.